# Seeking software to convert TIFF to TJP (Tiled JPEG)

Tags: geotiff-tiff, convert, software-recommendations, jpg

I have Tiff images and I need to export it to Tiled JPEG (TJP).

Which software converts TIFF to TJP?

Answer (score 2):

`TJP (JPEG TilePic)` is a `TilePic` format, alongside `TPC`, `TPG (PNG TilePic)` and `TTX (Text TilePic)` and can stores multiple images in a single file.

These formats aren't too popular in our days, and for this reason, it is hard to find much references.

This format can be read mainly by applications like [TilePic reader](http://www.rob-verhoeven.nl/wp/coding/tilepic-reader/) or [XnConvert](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnconvert/#formats), and, according to [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.106.1247&rep=rep1&type=pdf) article, the authors have provided *several tools for working with 
TilePic files. The basic TilePic utilities are fairly simple, are written in C, and require no additional libraries. [...] Also, there are a number of supporting programs and perl scripts to help with these applications.*

Because you are interested in converting `TIFF` to `TJP` here's the link to the [tifftotjp](https://saffron.caret.cam.ac.uk/svn/projects/darwincorresp/trunk/zoomify-generator/src/main/c/tilepic-1.2/tifftotjp.pl) Perl script.

And this is the [link](https://saffron.caret.cam.ac.uk/svn/projects/darwincorresp/trunk/zoomify-generator/src/main/c/) to all `TilePic` documentation and utilities.